# SQL GROUP BY CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to get the age of visitor from three tables:
Visits that holds the viist date by client ID, and
Clients that holds the Client ID, and
Clinic that holds the Clinic ID.

Here is my sql statement:

```
DECLARE @Clinicname nvarchar(50) 
SET @Clinicname='First Clinic'

SELECT CASE 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 20 THEN '11-20' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 30 THEN '21-30'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 40 THEN '31-40' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 50 THEN '41-50'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 60 THEN '51-60'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 70 THEN '61-70'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 80 THEN '71-80'
         ELSE '81+' 
       END AS age, 
       COUNT(*) AS n

FROM  Visit v 
          INNER JOIN  Client c ON v.ClientID = c.ClientID
          INNER JOIN  Clinic r ON v.ClinicId = r.ClinicId
          WHERE r.Name IN (@Clinicname)   
GROUP BY CASE 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 20 THEN '11-20' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 30 THEN '21-30'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 40 THEN '31-40' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 50 THEN '41-50'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 60 THEN '51-60'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 70 THEN '61-70'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, MIN(v.Date)) <= 80 THEN '71-80'
         ELSE '81+'
         END
```

Here is the error:
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

When I replace MIN(v.Date) with GETDATE() it works.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to calculate the person age.  For example the date of birth is 1/1/1950 and the visit date is 1/1/2011, I thought DATEDIFF will do that.

Comment: Aha. So you really don't need to have a min at all. Just v.Date

Comment: @Andrew, I think what's needed is the age at their FIRST visit, not at every visit.

Comment: Can you please specify the version of SQL Server and also the nature of the output. Do you want the number of people who were 1-10 at their first visit in one column, the number of people who were 11-20 in another column, or just the count and label in columns in each row? Is the count(*) supposed to represent the number of visits, the number of clients, the number of clinics, the number of visits by clients in an age group? Sample data and desired results will go a long way in trying to illustrate what you are trying to achieve. Right now it's not clear enough for any of us to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some guesses, based on loose specs, unknown version, etc. One piece of advice: `DATEDIFF(YEAR` is not a reliable way to calculate age. Think about cases where the person's birthday is in December and they have a visit in January, or vice versa. `DATEDIFF` only counts how many boundaries have been crossed, it doesn't care if the person's birthday has happened yet.

You could probably combine some of these query fragments, but chunking them out may make the logic more digestible.

**SQL Server 2005+**

```
;WITH vis AS
(
    SELECT 
        v.ClientId, 
        FirstVisit = MIN(v.[Date]), 
        NumVisits = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.Visit AS v
    INNER JOIN dbo.Clinic AS c
    ON c.ClinicId = v.ClinicId
    WHERE c.Name IN (@Clinicname)
    GROUP BY v.ClientId
),
ages AS (
    SELECT 
        v.ClientId,
        rough_age = DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.FirstVisit),
        v.NumVisits
    FROM vis AS v
    INNER JOIN dbo.Client AS c
    ON v.ClientId = c.ClientId
),
cats([group], numVisits) AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN rough_age/10 > 8 THEN '81+' ELSE
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), ((rough_age/10)+1)*10-9) + '-'
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ((rough_age/10)+1)*10) END,
        numVisits
   FROM ages
)
SELECT [group], NumClients = COUNT(*), NumVisits = SUM(numVisits)
FROM cats
GROUP BY [group];
```

**SQL Server 2000**

```
SELECT [group], NumClients = COUNT(*), NumVisits = SUM(numVisits)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [group] = CASE WHEN rough_age/10 > 8 THEN '81+' ELSE
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), ((rough_age/10)+1)*10-9) + '-'
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ((rough_age/10)+1)*10) END,
        numVisits
   FROM 
   (
    SELECT 
        v.ClientId,
        rough_age = DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.FirstVisit),
        v.NumVisits
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            v.ClientId, 
            FirstVisit = MIN(v.[Date]), 
            NumVisits = COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.Visit AS v
        INNER JOIN dbo.Clinic AS c
        ON c.ClinicId = v.ClinicId
        WHERE c.Name = @Clinicname
        GROUP BY v.ClientId
    ) AS v
    INNER JOIN dbo.Client AS c
    ON v.ClientId = c.ClientId
  ) AS ages
) AS cats
GROUP BY [group];
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron for the solution and also for expaining the DATEDIFF.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the grouping issue by using an inner query. This would be preferable in any case as you do not have to duplicate the bucketing logic.

I've also removed the MIN(v.Date) because I don't think that is really necessary.

```
DECLARE 
     @Clinicname nvarchar(50);

SET @Clinicname='First Clinic'


select age, count(*) from
(
    SELECT CASE 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.Date) <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.Date) <= 20 THEN '11-20' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.Date) <= 30 THEN '21-30'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.Date) <= 40 THEN '31-40' 
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.Date) <= 50 THEN '41-50'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.Date) <= 60 THEN '51-60'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.Date) <= 70 THEN '61-70'
         WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, c.BirthDate, v.Date) <= 80 THEN '71-80'
         ELSE '81+' 
       END AS age
    FROM  Visit v 
          INNER JOIN  Client c ON v.ClientID = c.ClientID
          INNER JOIN  Clinic r ON v.ClinicId = r.ClinicId
          WHERE r.Name IN (@Clinicname) 
) t group by age;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I got the following error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: @user373721: That's because there's a comma after age. I've fixed the syntax in the answer now.

Comment: Thanks, now I got this error Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'Client.BirthDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I used MIN to get the date of the first visit

Comment: Andrew, that would be the minimum of all visits by any client to any clinic, which is not what the original query attempts to do.

Comment: @John Saunders - there really isn't a need for MIN at all, is there? I'll remove that completely.